# How to add auto increment in postgreSQL?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I was trying to create a table and tried to add a primary key and auto increment in same column and came up with an ERROR

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SERIAL"
LINE 2:  upID int SERIAL primary key
```

Below is my Query

```
create table tblIK(
    upID int SERIAL primary key,
    upName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upMin varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upMax varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upYEAR Date NOT NULL,
    upMi varchar(100)NOT NULL,
    upIK varchar(100)NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SERIAL will create an integer column for you so you don't need to specify it.

```
create table tblIK(
    upID SERIAL primary key,
    upName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upMin varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upMax varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    upYEAR Date NOT NULL,
    upMi varchar(100)NOT NULL,
    upIK varchar(100)NOT NULL
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django to construct the tables in the DB and you want an auto incrementing primary key, Django by default will creat an ID column which is an auto incrementing integer field. Saves you some lines of code :)